# Why don't I see more constructors in rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It seems that I rarely, if ever, see or use a ruby constructor in a rails model.

My assumption is that because rails sets up so much stuff for you the need for initialization code is much lower.

Aren't there any good use cases for a constructor in a model though?

Comment: Good question. As someone who isn't doing web development, I jokingly thought that using a constructor in Rails would raise a `TooMuchMagicError`.

Comment: I've wondered the same thing myself. While the default constructor provided by ActiveRecord is adequate for parochial instance creation and a hook will allow custom initialization logic. My penchant for initializing stable instances and encapsulating the initialization logic in a single location that represents a widely recognized paradigm. Leaves me wanting a constructor. But when in Rome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with a constructor, just that they're hardly ever needed.
The main reason for a constructor would be for setting up default values. Setting default attributes, is easily done at the database level

```
add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
```

The main other thing that might be needed would be the existence/creation of an association model, this can be done either in a constructor/initializer, but what's more common is to use rails hooks to set a `before_create :populate_children, :ensure_parent_exists` (where populate_children, and ensure_parent_exists are private model methods) or something like that. This approach means that any initialization logic can be divided into logical methods (e.g. separate methods for each bit of initialization), and some can additionally be called at other times too `after_save :ensure_parent_exists`, and thus allows for more flexibility

Comment: To sum up: attributes can be set default values much more cleanly other ways, and alternatives to contructors like active records callbacks allow for a more flexible approach for more complicated requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you couldn't. Most of the important stuff is handled for you by ActiveRecord, but if you had some sort of specific initialization code you wanted to run, you could define your own constructor - just make sure it calls `super`.